# Learning react/redux and having an issue with connect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been attempting to teach myself react/redux and have run into a problem with the connect function. I'm trying to make a functioning game of chess, and all I want right now is to have a piece move to the selected square when it is clicked. I only have a single piece (a knight) right now, so i just need the knight to render where I click. The relevant code is as follows

Board.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Square from './Square';
import Knight from './Knight';
import { newPosition } from './index.js';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class Board extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    knightPosition: PropTypes.arrayOf(
      PropTypes.number.isRequired
    ).isRequired
  };

  renderSquare(i) {
    const x = i % 8;
    const y = Math.floor(i / 8);
    const black = (x + y) % 2 === 1;

    const [knightX, knightY] = this.props.knightPosition;
    const piece = (x === knightX && y === knightY) ?
      <Knight /> :
      null;

    return (
      <div key={i}
           style={{ width: '12.5%', height: '12.5%' }}
           onClick={() => this.props.newPosition(x, y)}>
        <Square black={black}>
          {piece}
        </Square>
      </div>
    );
 }

 render() {
    const squares = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
      squares.push(this.renderSquare(i));
    }

    return (
      <div style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
      }}>
        {squares}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({newPosition: newPosition}, dispatch)
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    knightPosition: state.knightPosition
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Board);
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Board from './Board';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

let knightPosition = [0,0];

//actions
export const newPosition = function(knightPosition) {
  return {
    type: 'MOVE_KNIGHT',
    knightPosition: knightPosition
  };
}

//reducers
var reducer = function(state=knightPosition, action) {
  console.log('reducer called with state', state, 'and action', action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'MOVE_KNIGHT':
      return {
        ...state,
        knightPosition: action.knightPosition
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

//store
let store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Board knightPosition={knightPosition} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I have left out the code of Squares and Knight to save space and because i don't think that's where the problem lies but I can paste it if needed.

I have been able to correctly record knightPosition in my state just using redux (when i click on square [4,6], getState() returns knightPosition: [4,6]) using different functions, but when i try to bind a function into props with connect  to my actual Board component so that the knight will also render in the correct square, I've gotten nothing but errors no matter what I attempt.

current error is as follows

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `knightPosition` is marked as required in `Board`, but its value is `undefined`.
in Board (created by Connect(Board))
in Connect(Board) (at index.js:41)
in Provider (at index.js:40)
```

and

```
fetch.js:461 Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance
```

which I assume is related to the first.

To troubleshoot I made a simpler version of the same problem, where instead of moving a knight around i just took a box and had it change color when I clicked on it, and it was successful.

I replaced newPosition() with

```
export const changeColor = function(black) {
    return {
        type: 'CHANGE_COLOR',
        black: !black
    };
}
```

and Board.js with

```
class App extends Component {
  static proptypes = {
    black: PropTypes.bool
  };

  render() {
    const { black } = this.props;
    const fill = black ? 'black' : 'white';
    const stroke = black ? 'white' : 'black';

    return (
      <div
      onClick= {() => this.props.changeColor(black)}
      style={{ 
        backgroundColor: fill,
        color: stroke,
        width: '50vw',
        height: '100vh',
      }}>
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({changeColor: changeColor}, dispatch)
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    black: state.black
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

The connect function here is identical to the one for board except i'm passing color boolean instead of a position array, but for some reason this one works and the other does not. I know I'm doing something wrong with connect but I cant figure out what. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: yea both failed prop type and non-iterable instance errors are showing up in the console.

Comment: <Board knightPosition={knightPosition} />

Why are you passing knightposition prop? It's the work of Provider. You do not need to send props.

Comment: I spot one problem with your redux state shape.. Check how you are defining your initial state (as an array), and in your `mapStateToProps` you are expecting an object with a prop `knightPosition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is with your redux state. In your reducer function, you are changing the state from an array (`knightPosition = [0,0]`) to an object (check state shape returned when handling the `MOVE_KNIGHT` action type):

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'MOVE_KNIGHT':
    // state change from an array to an object with a property `knightPosition`
    return {
      ...state,
      knightPosition: action.knightPosition
    };
    default:
      return state; // initial render return [0,0]
}
```

And the `mapStateToProps` function for your `Board` component is expecting to retrieve the knight coordinates from an object with `knightPosition` property:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    knightPosition: state.knightPosition
  };
}
```

---

In order to solve this, the minimum effort would be to modify your *default state* (currently defined as `let knightPosition = [0,0];`) to match the shape expected.

```
const DEFAULT_STATE = { knightPosition: [0,0] };
```

Then use this variable as state default argument:

```
var reducer = function(state = DEFAULT_STATE, action) { ... }
```

One more comment: As you are using the connected `Board` component you don't need to pass the `knightPosition` property inside the `render` call because it will retrieve that prop from the store:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    { /* no need to provide knightPosition prop here */ }
    <Board />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: this pretty much fixed it. I also had to pass this.props.newPosition an array of ([x , y]) instead of just (x, y), but its working as i want it to now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Console.log what you're returning from the reducer - is it what you expect?

```
case 'MOVE_KNIGHT':
  const newState = {
    ...state,
    knightPosition: action.knightPosition
  }
console.log('newState:', newState);
return newState;
```

I think you meant to make your default state `{knightPosition}` instead of `knightPosition`, so try swapping that in: `function(state={knightPosition}, action)`